# Looking for an small indoor desk plant

Tags: indoors, plant-recommendations

I am looking for a plant which :

- Is small, growing to atmost 1.5 feet (the smaller, the better)
- Requires minimal sunlight (at most, 1-2 hours of direct sunlight per day)
- Low risk of attracting pests
- Does not release pollen into the air (basically doesnt affect pollen allergies)
- Can survive from 4 degrees C to 48 degrees C

I am in India, so any suggestions for plants that I have a reasonable chance of finding here would be great.

Also, I am not looking for cacti, or anything with needles.

Comment: A plant that can survive to 4 degrees Celsius excludes most tropical plants that are houseplants.  Are you sure you do not heat the indoor area?

Comment: @kevinsky Of course, I do :) But, the heating isn't on when I am not physically present. Plus, the cold spurt lasts a week or two at most. I am not entirely sure if indoor temperatures drop that low, they certainly do go below 10.

Answer (score 4):

Common and successful one is [Lucky Bamboo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracaena_braunii), you can get this at any gift shop or malls or at any plant store.

[image]

Image Courtesy Wikipedia

You can also check more plants [here](http://tlc.howstuffworks.com/home/grow-office-plants.htm).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you hatiora salicornioides. It's a very interesting succulent plant, easy to grow and gives a lot of satisfaction!

[Wikipedia - Hatiora Salicornioides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhipsalis_salicornioides)